# Grails: importing plugin classes to _Events.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, classpath

I've created a Grails plugin which adds a custom test type class (extending `GrailsTestTypeSupport`) and custom test result class (extending `GrailsTestTypeResult`) to support a custom test type that I run during the `other` phase of the `test-app` script. Testing this on my local machine has gone swimmingly but...

When I packaged the plugin to use in my app, the tests are blowing up on our CI server (Jenkins). Here's the error that Jenkins is spitting out:

```
unable to resolve class CustomTestResult  @ line 58, column 9.
       new CustomTestResult(tests.size() - failed, failed)
```

It appears that I cannot simply `import` these classes into `_Events.groovy`, and the classes are not otherwise on the classpath. But I'll be damned if I can figure out how to get them onto the classpath. Here's what I have so far (in `_Events.groovy`):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor

eventAllTestsStart = {
  if (!otherTests) otherTests = []

  loadCustomTestResult()
  otherTests << createCustomTestType()
}

private def createCustomTestType(String name = 'js', String relativeSourcePath = 'js') {
  ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
  GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent)
  Class customTestTypeClass = loader.parseClass(new File("${customTestPluginDir}/src/groovy/custom/test/CustomTestType.groovy"))
  Constructor customTestTypeConstructor = customTestTypeClass.getConstructor(String, String)
  def customTestType = customTestTypeConstructor.newInstance(name, relativeSourcePath)

  customTestType
}

private def loadCustomTestResult() {
  ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
  GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent)
  Class customTestResultClass = loader.parseClass(new File("${customTestPluginDir}/src/groovy/custom/test/CustomTestResult.groovy"))
}
```

Currently: `CustomTestResult` is only referenced from within `CustomTestType`. As far as I can tell, `_Events.groovy` is loading `CustomTestType` but it is failing because it then insists that `CustomTestResult` is not on the classpath.

Putting aside for a moment that it seems crazy that there's this much overhead to get plugin-furnished classes onto the classpath for the test cycle to begin with... I'm not quite sure where I've gotten tripped up. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Ian Roberts'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592139/ian-roberts) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328510/grails-importing-plugin-classes-to-events-groovy/13345796#13345796) got me pointed in roughly the right direction, and combined with the `_Events.groovy` script from [this `grails-cucumber` plugin](https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/blob/master/scripts/_Events.groovy), I managed to come through with this solution:

First, `_Events.groovy` became this:

```
eventAllTestsStart = { if (!otherTests) otherTests = [] }

eventTestPhasesStart = { phases ->
  if (!phases.contains('other')) { return }

  // classLoader.loadClass business per Ian Roberts:
  otherTests << classLoader.loadClass('custom.test.CustomTestType').newInstance('js', 'js')
}
```

Which is far more readable than where I was at the start of this thread. But: I was in roughly the same position: my `ClassNotFoundException` moved from being thrown in `_Events.groovy` to being thrown from within `CustomTestType` when it tried to create an instance of `custom.test. CustomTestResult`. So within `CustomTestType`, I added the following method:

```
private GrailsTestTypeResult createResult(passed, failed) {
  try {
    return new customTestResult(passed, failed)
  } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
    Class customTestResult = buildBinding.classLoader.loadClass('custom.test.CustomTestResult')
    return customTestResult.newInstance(passed, failed)
  }
}
```

So Ian was right, inasmuch as `classLoader` came to the rescue -- I just wound up needing its magic in two places.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply loading the class in question via the ClassLoader that is accessible via the `classLoader` variable in `_Events.groovy`?

```
Class customTestTypeClass = classLoader.loadClass('custom.test.CustomTestType')
// use nice groovy overloading of Class.newInstance
return customTestTypeClass.newInstance(name, relativeSourcePath)
```

You should be late enough in the process at `eventAllTestsStart` for this to be valid.

Comment: So I must still have something wrong because that just seems to move the `ClassNotFoundException` from the place in `CustomTestType` which is trying to create an instance of `CustomTestResult`, to `_Events.groovy`.

Comment: @founddrama looking at the script, it appears that `eventAllTestsStart` will fire before the classloader has been set up, try `eventTestPhasesStart` instead.