# Importing classes for use in grails script _Events.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

In Grails `2.3.7` I'm using `_Events.groovy` to hook into WAR packaging to do some special processing:

#### _Events.groovy

```
    import demo.utils.XmlUtil

    eventCreateWarStart = { name, stageDir ->
       XmlUtil.doSomething()
       ...
       log.debug('done!')
    }
```

When building the WAR, Grails complains about `XmlUtil` import statement. `_Events.groovy` is not a class, so import statements don't work. How can I use a custom class in a script if I can't import it? And how can I perform logging instead of using `println`?

### Update

Loading classes manually based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390508/791406) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228360/791406) seems to do the trick, also got logging to work thanks to [Aaron's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24472947/791406) answer below:

```
 eventCreateWarStart = { name, stageDir ->

   def xmlUtil = loadRequiredClass('demo.utils.XmlUtil')
   xmlUtil.doSomething()
   ...
   grailsConsole.log('done!')
 }

 loadRequiredClass = {classname ->
   classLoader.loadClass(classname)
 }
```

### Questions

- What are all implicit objects available to Grails scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pain but it does make sense when you think about it. The `_Events.groovy` is part of the build process which is also responsible for compiling the classes that you are trying to use in `_Events.groovy`. Definitely a catch-22 scenario but I don't see how it could be made better without splitting `_Events.groovy` into separate files that compile and load at different stages of the build process.

You can use `grailsConsole.log("hi")` or `grailsConsole.updateStatus("hi")` to log output to the console.

Comment: Hi, thx, is there any difference between `println` and `grailsConsole.log()`?

Comment: Using grailsConsole guarantees that the output will look the same as other grails output. I'm not sure of the exact differences and it may vary by platform and depending on whether you use the --plain-output flag. (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/api/grails/build/logging/GrailsConsole.html)

Comment: thanks for the help, btw, where can I find all implicit objects available to a script? `grailsConsole`, `classLoader`, etc?

Comment: Easiest way is to just run `binding.variables.each { println it.key }` from inside of `_Events.groovy`. I can't recall exactly which binding class is used (maybe BuildSettings.groovy but I'm not 100% sure). Much of the build stuff changed in 2.3 and I haven't had a chance to get caught up fully.